# Terraform, ensure IAM policies are attached to an instance profile before creating the resources that use the profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating a resource that depends on an IAM instance profile, that profile in turn in being passed in policies that need to be attached.

For example I'm creating a resource from a module:

```
resource "lambda"{
    source = ../       
    policy_arns = data.policy
    dlq = var.dlq
}
```

The underlying module for this resource has a depends on an Instance Profile that's created in the same module:

```
module "instance_profile" {
  source                   = "../iam/instance-profile"
  policy_jsons             = var.policy_jsons
  policy_arns              = var.policy_arns
}

resource "lambda"{
  depends_on = [
    instance_profile.role_arn
  ]
}
```

This all works fine when the dlq is commented out, the issue seems to be that the attached policy (which contains the permission for sqs:SendMessage that lambda needs for the dlq) is not being attached before the lambda itself is being created.  I see the role is being created during the terraform step but the policies are not yet attached.

I've tried various things such as having a depends_on in the InstanceProfile module output so it depends upon itself and have tried depending on the attached policy arns in there also but I can't help but think there's a cleaner better way of doing this but so far haven't come across anything online that suggests a way to ensure the role is created in it's entirety including all attached policies before moving on to create the resources that use it.  I expected the lambda depending on the role to be enough but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: It sounds like there are multiple terraform resources being created, first a role, and later a policy that is attached to the role. You either need to depend on the `aws_iam_role_policy` or the `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` instead of just the role. Also it's weird you are calling this an instance profile, when instance profiles are only for EC2 instances, not Lambda functions.

Comment: Hey @MarkB - I think 'instance profile' is a hang on from some legacy code :( 
Within the module where the lambda and role are created I'm unable to depend on the policy or the attachment, however in the module that creates the role I do.  Would you suggest targeting the policies/attachments there instead?

Comment: I think you need to make the attachment an output of the module, and make your Lambda resource depend_on that attachment. I don't see any other way to do what you want.